# Javascript: hide a form input depending on the value of a particular drop-down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, drop-down-menu

Basically, I want to hide an input option depending based on the selected value of a drop-down menu.  Specifically, I only what to show this input tag if the value selected is tid and acc.

I have this drop-down menu.

```
<select id="select1742855Rule Type" onchange="document.getElementById('form1742855_Rule Type').value=this.value;">
        <option value="" selected="selected">None</option>
        <option value="tid">tid</option>
        <option value="tid and acc">tid and acc</option>
        <option value="xid">xid</option>
 </select>
```

And this input tag:

```
<input type="text" size="6" id = "acc" onchange="document.getElementById('form1742851_Id').value=this.value;">
```

I am a utter novice when it comes to javascript. Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: FYI spaces are not valid characters in an id.

Comment: Could you please, paste code that worked finally:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all: do no use white space in controls `id`

```
$('#select1742855Rule_Type').change(function() {
   var val = $(this).val();
   if (val == 'tid and acc') {
      $('#acc').show();
   }
   else {
      $('#acc').hide(); 
   }
});
```

Comment: I asked a follow up question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353403/javascript-hide-a-form-input-depending-on-the-value-of-a-particular-drop-down

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function() {
    $("yourInput").hide();
    $("yourSelect").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "yourVal")
            $("yourInput").show();
        else 
            $("yourInput").hide(); 
    }); 
});
```

Comment: Tried this code but didn't work: <script>$(function() {
    $("yourInput").hide();
    $("yourSelect").change(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == "yourVal")
            $("yourInput").show();
        else 
            $("yourInput").hide(); 
    }); 
});</script>
    <select id="yourSelect">
        <option value="" selected="selected">None</option>
        <option value="tid">tid</option>
        <option value="yourVal">yourVal</option>
        <option value="xid">xid</option>
 </select>
    <input type="text" size="6" id = "yourInput">

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

**NOTE**: Remove the space from the ID.

```
toggleInput = function(){    
    var select = document.getElementById("form1742855_Rule_Type");
    if (select){
        document.getElementById("acc").style.display = select.options[select.selectedIndex].value == "tid and acc" ? "block" : "none";    
    }
}
```