# Add text field if certain drop down is selected

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have a web form where I need to have an additional field displayed on the screen if a certain option is selected in a drop down list. I have followed several Javascript tutorials online and none have worked so far. Here is one of the things I already tried:

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    function setup(ans) {
      lit = ''
      if (ans == 'manual') {
        lit = 'Manual Selected'
        lit = lit + '<tr>'
        lit = lit + '<th align="right" class="body-text">Add New Group</th>'
        lit = lit + '<td class="body-text"><input type="text" name="groupadd">'
        lit = lit + '</td> </tr>'
     }
      document.getElementById('rep').innerHTML=lit
    }
    </script>
```

It doesn't work. What else can I try?

I have also seen "http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7353403/javascript-hide-a-form-input-depending-on-the-value-of-a-particular-drop-down" but it does not work for me either.

Thanks!

And this is what I want to add:

```
    <tr>
        <th align="right" class="body-text">Add New Group</th>
        <td class="body-text"><input type="text" name="groupadd"></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: Did you end up figuring this one out?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

```
  trElement = document.createElement('tr');

  thElement = document.createElement('th');
  thElement.className = "body-text";
  thElement.innerHTML = "Add New Group";

  trElement.appendChild(th);

  tdElement = document.createElement("td");
  tdElement.className = "body-text";
  inputElement = document.createElement("input");
  inputElement.type = "text";
  inputElement.name = "groupadd";

  tdElement.appendChild(inputElement);
  trElement.appendChild(tdElement);

  document.getElementById("new_field_div").appendChild(trElement);
```

Comment: Try to avoid `.innerHTML`. Use `.textContent`

Answer (score 0):

i am no html expert, but what u can do is that put the tr in div, and make its visibility hidden, and when certain option is selected, get id of div in javascript and set its visibility = visible....

thats just an idea...

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want vanilla javascript then you need to set the visibility of the element to hidden on page load and show it when the option is selected.

The basic syntax is:

```
document.getElementById('hideshow').style.visibility = 'hidden';
document.getElementById('hideshow').style.visibility = 'visible';
```

where 'hideshow' is the id of the element you want to modify.

See http://www.webmasterworld.com/forum91/441.htm for examples on how to do this.